# Mongo find() within specific array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find items with a specific path \ parent.

Example data:

Document A:

```
{
  "traces": [{
      "act": {
        "account": "555",
        "name": "Bob"
      }
    },
    {
      "act": {
        "account": "666",
        "name": "Mary"
      }
    }    
  ],
  "other": [{
      "act": {
        "account": "555",
        "volume": "PPPPP"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Document B:

```
{
  "traces": [
    {
      "act": {
        "account": "666",
        "name": "Mary"
      }
    }    
  ],
  "other": [{
      "act": {
        "account": "555",
        "volume": "PPPPP"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So when searching the above two document, I want my search to match Document A but NOT document B

If I use the below find statement:

```
db.action_traces.find({ "act.account" : { $in: [ "555" ]}).limit().forEach(function(result){
print(.....);
});
```

It seems like it will match A and B because both have an elements under the "other" section that matches.

How can I specify that I only want to match traces.{Any Element In Array}.act.account  ?

Comment: `db.action_traces.find({ "traces.act.account" : { $in: [ "555" ]})` ??

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Perhaps I made a mistake in my initial test as that's what I was hoping would work. I'll re-test.

Comment: No that definitely does not work.

Comment: It is working https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dgit0kwAq67 ?